# Projection onto rotated box

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Does anyone know if there is an efficient way to find the projection of an arbitrary point $z$ onto a rotated box, i.e. onto the set $\Omega=\{x \mid a \leq Ux \leq b\}$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix?

A naive solution would first rotate $z$, which has a complexity $O(n^2)$, and then the problem reduces to projecting onto a non-rotated box, which can be solved in $O(n)$.

However, in my application (essentially proximal gradient descent) I would need to solve this subproblem a lot of times, and $n$ would be in the order of several millions. Thus $O(n^2)$ per call is not an affordable complexity. The value of $z$ would change among calls, but $a$, $b$ and $U$ would be the same for all calls. Hence, any way of exploiting the fact that $a$, $b$ and $U$ are constant which results in reduced complexity across calls for different values of $z$ would be extremely beneficial.

Is there a way to reduce the complexity of the naive approach or is $O(n^2)$ per call the best one can achieve for this projection problem?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to rotate $k$ vectors at once.  Consider the matrix $M$ formed by concatenating these $k$ vectors (so $M$ is an $n\times k$ matrix, and each column of $M$ is one of the original vectors).

Then we can rotate all $k$ vectors by computing the product

$$ UM $$

Naively, this would take $O(kn^2)$ steps.  There exist "fast" matrix multiplication algorithms for rectangular matrices; a nice treatment of that can be found in [Francois Le Gall's "Faster Algorithms for Rectangular Matrix Multiplication"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1111).  The complexity depends on the size of $k$ relative to $n$.

For example, if $k=O(\sqrt{n})$, then the naive running time of $O(n^{2.5})$ could be improved to $O(n^{2.046681})$.

Of course, these results are only asymptotic; in real life, these algorithms would probably be totally inappropriate.

Comment: Sadly, that wouldn't help even in the asymptotic regime because the calls are sequential. In other words, to compute let's say, the second column of the matrix $M$ you propose, you need to know the solution of the projection problem when $z$ is the first column of $M$. I was hoping to find something able to exploit that $U$, $a$ and $b$ are constant for all calls, but I suspect it's probably impossible. If it was possible, solving a general QP subject to box constraints would have complexity almost equal to computing an eigendecomposition. Then, interior point methods would be kinda pointless

Comment: (for that specific problem, not for more general tasks of course)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this points in the right direction since I don't know enough context. It seems like you could in principle set $y= Ux$ and either work with the rotated variable all over the place or use "splitting", i.e. consider $y=Ux$ as a new equality constraint in your original problem. Whether one of this options is practical depends very much on the context.

Comment: To be more exact, I want to solve a QP with a single linear equality constraint and box-inequality constraint (SVM problem in machine learning). However, the hessian of the quadratic cost function has a very especial structure in my application. The main advantage such structure has is that computing an eigendecomposition is much cheaper than the naive O(n^3). My idea is to design a special SVM solver that exploits such circumstance. Now, I am using ADMM by introducing a constraint y=Ux as you said. But to do so, either I solve the subproblem I mentioned, or do two products Ux per iteration.

Comment: Right, an additional equality constraint does not help if you can not afford multiplication by $U$ in every iteration. Did I get it right, that also rotating the whole problem is not an option since this would destroy some preferable structure of your objective function?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the issue. I am still doubting whether what I want to achieve makes any sense at all. Strictly speaking, I am looking for a SVM solver which, given that you know the eigendecomposition of the hessian (kernel matrix) has subquadratic per-iteration cost. Also all coordinates are updated in every iteration (not a coordinate-descent approach like SMO). If such a thing was possible, we could still apply this to generic problems and get a solution essentially in a "one-shot" O(n^3), since the cost of iterations would be then negligible.